# How to detect if a certain image is present or not in Python

Tags: python, image, conditional-statements, pyautogui, rpa

I'm trying to create a robot that executes an condition if a certain image is present, but another if the image isn't on the screen. It's possible to do that with pyautogui? If it isn't which library can I use instead?

The program works fine if the image is on the screen, but sometimes it will be not be present so the program show an error.

```
print('Robô iniciado...')
p.hotkey('win', 'r')
p.sleep(2)
p.typewrite('C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe')
p.sleep(3)
p.press('enter')
p.sleep(5)
janela = p.getActiveWindow()
janela.maximize()
p.sleep(4)
p.click(x=102, y=48)
p.sleep(2)
p.typewrite('Ulsan CG Oficina')
p.sleep(3)
p.press('down')
p.press('enter')
p.sleep(10)
p.click(x=300, y=300)
p.sleep(3)
localRem = p.locateOnScreen('Remmina.png', confidence=0.7)
localRemmina = p.center(localRem)
xRem, yRem = localRemmina
p.moveTo(xRem, yRem, duration=1)
p.doubleClick(xRem, yRem)
p.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "a robot that executes an condition if a certain image is present, but another if the image isn't on the screen" What screen are you talking about? Please read [ask], and give more context for the problem.

Comment: "It's possible to do that with pyautogui?" Well, it seems like you wrote code that's intended to try. Did something go wrong? What happens when you try the code? What is supposed to happen, and how is that different?

Comment: The code fragment is unhelpful. Please try to write the minimal code that could debug what you are intending, including the creation of the `p` object and maybe some documentation link to that `locateOnScreen` function.

Also `p` is pretty bad variable name for a code you are sharing: don't paste your code fragments as is, format them as if a stranger had to review it, because that's what we are doing!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the error is when your image `Remmina.png` is not on screen and so cannot be found.

[The pyautogui docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) say that:

> NOTE: As of version 0.9.41, if the locate functions can’t find the provided image, they’ll raise ImageNotFoundException instead of returning None.

So, it would be a good idea to put the locate function in a try-except block. Also, use `locateCenterOnScreen` instead of `locateOnScreen` + `center`.

Here is your code with the try-except.

```
.
.
.
p.click(x=300, y=300)
p.sleep(3)
try:
    localRemmina = p.locateCenterOnScreen('Remmina.png', confidence=0.7)
    xRem, yRem = localRemmina
    p.moveTo(xRem, yRem, duration=1)
    p.doubleClick(xRem, yRem)
    p.sleep(3)

except p.ImageNotFoundException:
    # do something else here
```

**If this is not what you wanted, please comment with the details :)**